# Javascript : Check if object has properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

There are several answers here how to check if a property exists in an object.

I was always using

```
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty('propName'))
```

but I wonder if there is any difference from

```
if('propName' in myObj){
```

Comment: why not just "if (myObj.propName)"?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-undefined/17

Comment: hey guys, thankyou - sorry, did not find the mentioned dup.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They are almost equal, the difference is that `hasOwnProperty` does not check down the prototype chain, while `in` does.

An example

```
var test = function() {}

test.prototype.newProp = function() {}

var instance = new test();

instance.hasOwnProperty('newProp'); // false
'newProp' in instance // true
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/x6FQ5/)

As noted, `Object.hasOwnProperty` only returns *"own properties"*, i.e. properties that are added directly, and not properties added to the `prototype`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is difference. `hasOwnProperty()` ignores properties and methods which are added with `prototype`. I try to explain with examples. For instance if you have prototype of object

```
Object.prototype.something = function() {};
```

And let's say you have following `object`

```
var obj = {
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : "two"
};
```

And loop:

```
for ( var i in obj ) {
    //if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(obj[i]);
    //}
}
```

Without `hasOwnProperty` it will output `one two function()`, while with `hasOwnProperty()` method only `one two`

See the differences between [First](http://jsfiddle.net/xPMne) and [Second](http://jsfiddle.net/xPMne/1/) DEMOS